# Podcast downloader

Tags: bash, curl, sed, grep, wget

As part of a project to learn bash scripting I'm writing an RSS podcast downloader. I've seen plenty of examples using tools such as cURL, wget and further parsing the XML using grep, sed and awk. Here is a one liner from [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/14685/download-files-linked-in-a-rss-feed) that does the job.

```
curl $1 | grep -E "http.*\.mp3" | sed "s/.*\(http.*\.mp3\).*/\1/" | xargs wget
```

Would this be the most efficient way of parsing an RSS looking for MP3s? The RSS feed contains links to several hundred MP3s and my next goal will be to only download the latest 10.

Comment: Part of my confusion is when to use grep/sed/awk for parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, with an XML RSS format you could use the `xpath` utility to select the specific nodes you want.

If the example `sed` statement is, by chance, producing an ordered list of mp3 urls, you could use the `head` or `tail` utilities to pull out the first or last 10 items (depending on sort order).  However, note that blindly parsing the feed without using an XML aware parser may result in a fragile solution.

It is hard to be too much more specific without more details.

Comment: Interested to know why I should be using an xml parser. I listen to this feed - http://podcast.securityweekly.com/    - specifically the "Security Weekly" and "Enterprise Security Weekly" podcasts. I want to craft my script accordingly to only the latest episodes. This is something that I planned to write in bash and then duplicate in Python in an attempt to learn scripting languages. If I will run into headaches writing it in bash then I will need to consider skipping ahead to Python.

Comment: @Heisenberg If you look at the feed you will notice it uses an XML format: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.  Am I misunderstanding your question?  I expect you can achieve your goal with either a bash script or Python.

Comment: Security Weekly uses RSS v.2.0. Prior to now I did not fully understand the difference between XML and RSS.

Comment: @Heisenberg RSS uses an XML format.  You can get more information from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) or the [RSS 2.0 Specification](http://cyber.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I will try my hand writing this with Python.

Comment: @Heisenberg sounds good.  For reference, this might be a better link for the [RSS Specification](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification).  Also there are [Python libraries](https://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries) that are tailored for parsing RSS.